# On a $n \times n \times n$ Rubiks cube, how many combinations are there?

Tags: combinatorics

I have a $n \times n \times n$ sized Rubiks cube, how many combinations are there in terms of $n$?

Comment: [This](http://www.speedcubing.com/chris/ccproof.html) may answer your question. $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ is the [floor function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FloorFunction.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Cubers/comments/43xzov/mathematical_counting_formulas_for_number_of/) of mine on Reddit.  I link to all kinds of Rubik's Cube math expressions to Wolfram|Alpha for fast and easy computation.  I also have formulas for the number of positions of the n-layered megaminx family as well.

Comment: Maybe give a reference to the precise location. It's a long passage